# No logro entender un detalle del índice del bucle "for" en Javascript

Tags: javascript, bucle-for

Estuve horas intentando resolver un ejercicio, y gracias a chat gpt pude resolverlo pero hubo algo que no entendí, y le pedí a la ia para que lo explique, pero me lo explicó 15 veces mínimo y no lo pude entender. El código en cuestión es este:

```
const isArmstrong = (num) => {
      const numString = num.toString(); 
      const numDigits = numString.length; 
      let count = 0;
    
      for (let i = 0; i < numDigits; i++) {
        let digits = numString[i];
        count += digits ** numDigits;
      }
    
      return num === count;
    };
```

Lo que no entiendo es esta linea:

```
let digits = numString[i];
```

No entiendo como es que puedo hacer "numString[i]" sin haber recorrido nunca numString, lo que recorrí fue numDigits, y yo lo que pensaba / lo que tengo entendido es que al índice de una variable puedo acceder usando un bucle for recorriendo esa variable, y de vuelta, no recorrí numString sino que recorrí numDigits. ¿Como es que puedo acceder al índice de numString si no lo recorrí nunca?

Comment: Al hacer numString = num.toString(); , ese contendrá una cadena de caracteres con el numero "num", de manera que si num=321, entonces numString contendra una cadena de 3 caracteres "3","2" y "1", que ocuparan los espacios [0],[1] y [2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te estás confundiendo un poco, empecemos aclarando la "**condición**" del bucle for.

```
for( let i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
    hagoAlgo();
}
```

La expresión **`i < array.length;`** es la condición que le indica al for, si debe seguir iterando, en este caso, mientras "**`i`**" sea menor que la longitud de **`array`**, el bucle sigue, ahora bien, eso no quiere decir que necesariamente esté iterando sobre el `array`, puede que si, puede que no, lo que está entre "**`{}`**", es lo que define sobre que `array` itera... si es que itera sobre alguno.
Vamos con un ejemplo bien tonto (no se porqué son los que se me vienen a la cabeza).

```js
let array = [ 0, 1 ]; 
let mensajes = [ "hola", "genio", "que", "estás", "haciendo" ]; 
for( let i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
    console.log( mensajes[ i ] );
}
```

En la consola se va a imprimir:

```
hola
genio
```

Osea, usé el la longitud del `array` de números, para limitar las iteraciones del `for`, pero iteré sobre el `array` de palabras.

Answer (score 0):

Realmente no estás "recorriendo" `numDigits`, lo que haces es iterar `numDigits` veces.

Si te fijas, `numDigits` va a almacenar el número de dígitos que hay en `numString` para posteriormente iterar las veces necesarias para realizar tus cálculos.

Con un ejemplo quizás lo veas más claro. Tu código es lo mismo que esto:

```
const isArmstrong = (num) => {
      const numString = num.toString(); 
      let count = 0;
    
      for (let i = 0; i < numString.length; i++) {
        let digits = numString[i];
        count += digits ** numString.length;
      }
    
      return num === count;
    };
```